# El emulador IOS no toma el click sobre el boton

Tags: react-native

Me esta pasando lo siguiente tengo abierto el emulador de ios con xcode mientras desarrollo la app en `react-native` pero cada vez que le doy al click sobre el emulador Ios esta funcion no se ejecuta por lo tanto no me muestra el log. Sin embargo abri la app con Expo y al darle al darle sobre el boton llama a la funcion que me brinda el log, Sera una configuracion propia de xcode?. Adjunto mi codigo.

Es como que el `onPress` nunca se ejecuta desde el emulador pero si desde expoGo

```
    // React-native
    import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';

    // Native-base provider
    import { Text, Box, Stack, Button } from "native-base";

    const screenDimensions = Dimensions.get('screen').width;

    const InitialAskingScreen = ({navigation}) => {

        useEffect(() => {
            // callTest();
        }, [])
        const callTest = () => {
            console.log('calling...')
        }
        return(
            <Box flex={1} justifyContent='center' justifyItems={'center'} bg={'#fff'}>
                <Box mb={20}>
                    <Text textAlign={'center'} fontWeight='600' fontSize='20px'>Bienvenido a app</Text>
                </Box>
                <Box justifyContent='center' alignItems={'center'}>
                    <Stack space={4}>
                        <Box bg={'blue'}>
                            <Button colorScheme="none" bg={'blue.500'} borderRadius={15} w={screenDimensions - 30}>
                                <Text color='white' fontWeight={'500'}>Registrate</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </Box>

                        <Box>
                            <Button onPress={() => console.log("hello world")} colorScheme='none' bg={'white'} borderColor={'blue.400'} borderWidth={2} borderRadius={15} w={screenDimensions - 30}>
                                <Text>Ingresa</Text>
                            </Button>
                        </Box>
                    </Stack>
                </Box>
            </Box>
```